# Parse.com parseuser isnt saved on server when calling .save() android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im trying to update the current user in the remote User table using save(); but the user is saved only in the local object. what im doing:

```
                   ArrayList<String> usedCoupons = new ArrayList<String>();
                usedCoupons.add(couponName);
                if (currentUser.getList("used_coupons") != null) {
                    currentUser.getList("used_coupons").addAll(usedCoupons);
                } else {
                    currentUser.put("used_coupons", usedCoupons);
                }

                try {
                    currentUser.save();

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "קוד שגוי, אנא נסה שנית", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

This function always works and i can see that the coupons are being saved locally, but when i look in the parse core panel, the object is not being updated. Any idea on how can i force the parse user to sync remotely?

Comment: I do not see you call ```saveInBackground()``` in your code.

Comment: You're right, changed it to .save();

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

`currentUser.save();`

to this..

`currentUser.saveInBackground();`

Comment: Iv'e tried it both save(); and saveInBackground(); and none of them work